# Pyramid pattern in Java using for loop

Tags: java

I want to print the pyramid pattern using word "Stream" by using for loop in Java. Please anyone can help me with this. I have printed pyramid with "*". I have also attached the program below:

Desired Result:

```
                          S
                        S   t
                      S   t   r
                    S   t   r   e
                 S    t   r   e    a
              S     t   r   e    a    m
```

What I have so far:

```
public class Pyramid
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

      System.out.println("-----Pyramid------");
      int n = 5;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
          System.out.print(" ");
        for (int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++)
          System.out.print("S");
        System.out.print("\n");
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes.. I have done the pyramid by using *.But i want Stream word instead of "*".

Comment: Instead of showing us your succesfull trial to get what you actually don't want, try to get what you want and come back if you don't get it. Starting with what you already got, this is really not such a big deal.

Comment: One idea would be to put the letters of Stream in an array: `char[] letters = {'S', 't', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm'};` then access the correct letter with your loop counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with any word.
As a hint I'd recommend to start loops with 0 instead of 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-----Pyramid------");
        String word = "Stream";
        int n = word.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n+2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++)
                System.out.print(word.charAt(k) + " ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
-----Pyramid------


         S 
        S t 
       S t r 
      S t r e 
     S t r e a 
    S t r e a m
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `charAt` method in order to extract from the word Stream the chars you need inside the loop to create the pyramid

For example:

```
"Stream".charAt(0);
```

Will print the char `S`

```
"Stream".charAt(3);
```

Will print the char `e`.

More info here: [String class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))